# Tim sort giving error on the number of elements that are not power of 2

Tags: c++, sorting, timsort

I'm trying to implement Timsort algorithm to sort random signed integers into non-decreasing order. This algorithm sorts signed integers well when the number of integers are relatively small however when the number gets bigger it seems to fail to sort when the number of signed integers is not power of 2.

For example, it sorts well 256 random signed integers but it fails to sort 257, 258, 259, 260 or 261 signed integers. But then it sorts well 512, 511, 510 signed integers. I cannot find what causes this inconsistent result where for some numbers of elements that are not power of two it works, and for some other numbers of elements that are not power of two it fails.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <stdint.h>

const int RUN = 32;

void insertionSort(int* list, int left, int right){
    for(int i = left+1; i <= right; i++){
    int temp = list[i];
    int j = i - 1;
    while(list[j] > temp && j >= left){
        list[j+1] = list[j];
        j--;
    }
    list[j+1] = temp;
    }
}

void merge(int* list, int l, int m, int r){
    if( l == r) return; //
    int len1 = m - l + 1, len2 = r - m;
    int* left = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*len1);
    int* right = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*len2);

    for(int i = len1; i--;) left[i] = list[l + i];

    for(int i = len2; i--;) right[i] = list[m + 1 + i];
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = l;
    //merging into larger sub array
    while(i < len1 && j < len2){
    if( left[i] <= right[j]){
            list[k] = left[i];
        i++;
    }
    else{
        list[k] = right[j];
        j++;
        }
    k++;
    }
    //copy remaining part
    while(i < len1){
    list[k] = left[i];
    k++; i++;
    }
    while(j < len2){
    list[k] = right[j];
    k++; j++;
    }
}

void algorithm_4(int* list, int input_size) { //tim sort
   int* list2 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*input_size);
   for(int i = 0; i < input_size; i++){
       list2[i] = list[i+1];
   }
   //for(int i = 1; i <= input_size; i+=RUN){
   for(int i = 0 ; i < input_size; i+=RUN){
     insertionSort(list2, i,std::min((i+31), (input_size-1)));
   }
   for(int size = RUN; size < input_size; size = size * 2){
     for(int left = 0; left < input_size; left += size * 2){
    int right;
    if(input_size - 1 < 2*(2*size - 1)){
           right = input_size -1;
    }
    else right = std::min((left+2*size-1), (input_size-1));
    int mid = (left + right) / 2;
    merge(list2, left, mid, right);
          }
   }
   for(int i = 0; i<input_size; i++){
       list[i+1] = list2[i];
   }
}
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve].

Comment: Do not tag both C and C++ unless a question involves both. This code uses C++ features and is not C code.